# Get access token for a google cloud service account in Golang?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm using a service account on google cloud. For some reason, I want to get the access token programmatically in golang. I can do `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` on the command line.

There is a [library by google](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20220309155454-6242fa91716a/google?utm_source=gopls) that seems to allow me to get the token. Here is how I try to use it:

```
    credentials, err := auth.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx)
    if err == nil {
        glog.Infof("found default credentials. %v", credentials)
        token, err2 := credentials.TokenSource.Token()
        fmt.Printf("token: %v, err: %v", token, err2)
        if err2 != nil {
            return nil, err2
        }
```

However, I get an error saying `token: <nil>, err: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request`.

I already have `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable defined and pointing to the json file.

Comment: the `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token' doesn't work with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL` env var. One use your user credentials, the other use the service account key file. Can you detail how to you define your env var, the pattern of the json file (not the content, it's secret!),... please share more!

Comment: I ended up at this page due to specifying a non-existent oauth scope in my call to google.CredentialsFromJSON. The idtoken library doesn't use scopes, so it gave me what I wanted, but the underlying problem was really just that my oauth scope was specified incorrectly. Once I resolved that I could use the ordinary authentication libraries as normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running your code as-is, returns an err:

```
Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided
```

I added the catch-all Cloud Platform writable scope from [Google's OAuth scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

Doing so, appears to work. See below:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    auth "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
)

func main() {
    var token *oauth2.Token
    ctx := context.Background()
    scopes := []string{
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    }
    credentials, err := auth.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx, scopes...)
    if err == nil {
        log.Printf("found default credentials. %v", credentials)
        token, err = credentials.TokenSource.Token()
        log.Printf("token: %v, err: %v", token, err)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
    }
}
```

I had some challenges using this library recently (to access Cloud Run services which require a JWT audience). On a friend's recommendation, I used [`google.golang.org/api/idtoken`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/idtoken) instead. The API is very similar.

Comment: haha, I just came here to provide the answer that you posted since I just figured out the same solution! Thanks

Comment: I found that running locally I needed to first run `gcloud auth application-default login`- I was trying to create a GCP instance and was able to do that with `gcloud compute instances create [...]` but could not do so programmatically without first running the aforementioned command.