# Is there a way to generate access token using gcp service account without using gcloud or cmd?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console

Problem statement: I have to use docker endpoints for my Google Artifact Registry.

The url will look like

```
GET https://<region>-docker.pkg.dev/v2/_catalog
```

The inputs which I have is service account json key. I am unable to find a way like how to use the service account for authentication purpose.

FYI: I have tried this api by manually generating access token from cmd using `gcloud auth print-access-token` and using that bearer token for authentication, and it worked fine.

To do: find a way to do the same by utilizing my service account json file.

I have tried several ways to do this.

Referred to these docs:

1. [Generating short lived access token](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct#user-credentials_2)

   Here at last what I found is anyways we need that access token, to use any REST API :)
2. [Authorizing requests for service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests)

   I am unable to clearly understand the steps, like computing signature.

Can somebody please suggest a way to solve this issue? I don't want to interact with cmd in any way.

- Programming language in use: Golang
- Tools for testing APIs: Postman

Comment: This will help using the SDK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72282311/8016720 The SDK includes methods to create credentials/tokens from multiple sources.